# Allocation too large< ~lib/rt/itcms.ts<$Index out of range,~lib/rt.ts when execute AssemblyScript code

Tags: go, webassembly, assemblyscript

I'm stuck on this when learing web assembly.

basically I have this `index.ts` file written in assembly script

```js
// The entry file of your WebAssembly module.

class Animal {
  constructor() {}
  name: i32;
  age: i32;
}

export function newAnimal(): i32 {
  let animal = new Animal();
  animal.name = 1;
  animal.age = 2;

  return 1;
}
```

I compile with the following command

```
npx  asc assembly/index.ts --target release --use abort=assembly/index/myAbort
```

However when i check the `realease.wat` file it has some weird messages

```
 (memory $0 1)
 (data $0 (i32.const 12) "<\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\02\00\00\00(\00\00\00A\00l\00l\00o\00c\00a\00t\00i\00o\00n\00 \00t\00o\00o\00 \00l\00a\00r\00g\00e\00\00\00\00\00")
 (data $1 (i32.const 76) "<\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\02\00\00\00 \00\00\00~\00l\00i\00b\00/\00r\00t\00/\00i\00t\00c\00m\00s\00.\00t\00s\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00")
 (data $2 (i32.const 144) "\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00")
 (data $3 (i32.const 176) "\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00")
 (data $4 (i32.const 204) "<\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\02\00\00\00$\00\00\00I\00n\00d\00e\00x\00 \00o\00u\00t\00 \00o\00f\00 \00r\00a\00n\00g\00e\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00")
 (data $5 (i32.const 268) ",\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\02\00\00\00\14\00\00\00~\00l\00i\00b\00/\00r\00t\00.\00t\00s\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00")
 (data $6 (i32.const 320) "\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00")
 (data $7 (i32.const 348) "<\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\02\00\00\00\1e\00\00\00~\00l\00i\00b\00/\00r\00t\00/\00t\00l\00s\00f\00.\00t\00s\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00")
 (data $8 (i32.const 416) "\06\00\00\00 \00\00\00 \00\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00 \00\00\00 \00\00\00")
```

I decode this Unicode message and got this error

`<(Allocation too large< ~lib/rt/itcms.ts<$Index out of range,~lib/rt.ts@@<~lib/rt/tlsf.ts`

I execute this using go-wasmtime and also got the same error

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "C"

    "github.com/bytecodealliance/wasmtime-go/v9"
)



func main() {
    // Load the WebAssembly module from file

    // Almost all operations in wasmtime require a contextual `store`
    // argument to share, so create that first
    engine := wasmtime.NewEngine()
    store := wasmtime.NewStore(engine)
    linker := wasmtime.NewLinker(engine)

    vals := map[int32]int32{}

    set := func(k, v int32) {
        vals[k] = v
        fmt.Printf("set: %d, %d\n", k, v)
    }

    get := func(k int32) int32 {
        fmt.Printf("get: %d\n", k)
        return vals[k]
    }

    linker.DefineFunc(store, "kv", "set", set)
    linker.DefineFunc(store, "kv", "get", get)

    module, err := wasmtime.NewModuleFromFile(engine, "./release.wasm")
    check(err)

    // Create the WASI instance
    wasiConfig := wasmtime.NewWasiConfig()
    store.SetWasi(wasiConfig)

    check(err)

    instance, err := linker.Instantiate(store, module)

    check(err)

    mem := instance.GetExport(store, "memory").Memory()
    fmt.Printf("mem = %+v\n", mem)
    ptr := mem.Data(store)
    // Allocate memory
    fmt.Printf("Go: wasm sandbox memory info: size %d, data size %d\n",
        mem.Size(store),
        mem.DataSize(store),
    )
    buf := mem.UnsafeData(store)
    fmt.Printf("Go: wasm sandbox memory content: %s\n", string(buf))

}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
```

Output

```
mem = &{val:{store_id:1 index:0}}
Go: wasm sandbox memory info: size 512, data size 33554432
Go: wasm sandbox memory content: <(Allocation too large< ~lib/rt/itcms.ts<$Index out of range,~lib/rt.ts@@<~lib/rt/tlsf.ts
```

Thank you a lot if any one can give me instruction on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you share the abort function? I have a hunch that your source simply contain those messages, and they are copied verbatim in the wasm module as intended. Them being there doesn't seem to mean that something went wrong.

Can you also try a `strings` on that wasm module?